# How to implement pagination in React

Tags: reactjs, pagination

I am new to ReactJS and am creating a simple TODO application in it. Actually, it is a very basic app with no DB connection, tasks are stored in an array. I added Edit and Delete functionality to it now I want to add pagination.

How do I implement it? Any help will be appreciated. Thank you...!!

Comment: You can search the keyword `reactjs todo` in Github. You would get a lot of samples.I suggest you to study them first

Comment: Yah I referred same for above functionality. but for pagination, I didn't find any help there.

Comment: [react-paginate]
(https://github.com/AdeleD/react-paginate)

Comment: i have created pagination in pure reactjs : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51982376/pager-creation-using-reactjs-net

Answer (score 175, accepted):

I've implemented pagination in pure React JS recently. Here is a working demo: http://codepen.io/PiotrBerebecki/pen/pEYPbY

You would of course have to adjust the logic and the way page numbers are displayed so that it meets your requirements.

Full code:

```
class TodoApp extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      todos: ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k'],
      currentPage: 1,
      todosPerPage: 3
    };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick(event) {
    this.setState({
      currentPage: Number(event.target.id)
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { todos, currentPage, todosPerPage } = this.state;

    // Logic for displaying todos
    const indexOfLastTodo = currentPage * todosPerPage;
    const indexOfFirstTodo = indexOfLastTodo - todosPerPage;
    const currentTodos = todos.slice(indexOfFirstTodo, indexOfLastTodo);

    const renderTodos = currentTodos.map((todo, index) => {
      return <li key={index}>{todo}</li>;
    });

    // Logic for displaying page numbers
    const pageNumbers = [];
    for (let i = 1; i <= Math.ceil(todos.length / todosPerPage); i++) {
      pageNumbers.push(i);
    }

    const renderPageNumbers = pageNumbers.map(number => {
      return (
        <li
          key={number}
          id={number}
          onClick={this.handleClick}
        >
          {number}
        </li>
      );
    });

    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          {renderTodos}
        </ul>
        <ul id="page-numbers">
          {renderPageNumbers}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(
  <TodoApp />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Comment: Another hands on tutorial to build a paginated list in React: https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-paginated-list/

Comment: I don't understand how do you reload your list of elements after calling the handleClick method? I'm trying to refresh the list without reload the page. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Take a look here: https://hemanta.io/implement-pagination-search-and-filter-in-a-react-app-part-3/

Answer (score 15):

I have tried to recreate the simple pagination example given by [piotr-berebecki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4186037/piotr-berebecki) which was great. But when there will be a lot of pages then the pagination will overflow in the screen. So, I used previous and back button along with forward and backward button to stream back and forth between the pages. And for design part I have used bootstrap 3.

You can customize no of pages to display in pagination using the pagebound values. Make sure to use same value for upperPageBound and pageBound.

```
    class TodoApp extends React.Component {
          constructor() {
            super();
            this.state = {
              todos: ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m',
'n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'],
              currentPage: 1,
              todosPerPage: 3,
              upperPageBound: 3,
              lowerPageBound: 0,
              isPrevBtnActive: 'disabled',
              isNextBtnActive: '',
              pageBound: 3
            };
            this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
            this.btnDecrementClick = this.btnDecrementClick.bind(this);
            this.btnIncrementClick = this.btnIncrementClick.bind(this);
            this.btnNextClick = this.btnNextClick.bind(this);
            this.btnPrevClick = this.btnPrevClick.bind(this);
            // this.componentDidMount = this.componentDidMount.bind(this);
            this.setPrevAndNextBtnClass = this.setPrevAndNextBtnClass.bind(this);
          }
          componentDidUpdate() {
                $("ul li.active").removeClass('active');
                $('ul li#'+this.state.currentPage).addClass('active');
          }
          handleClick(event) {
            let listid = Number(event.target.id);
            this.setState({
              currentPage: listid
            });
            $("ul li.active").removeClass('active');
            $('ul li#'+listid).addClass('active');
            this.setPrevAndNextBtnClass(listid);
          }
          setPrevAndNextBtnClass(listid) {
            let totalPage = Math.ceil(this.state.todos.length / this.state.todosPerPage);
            this.setState({isNextBtnActive: 'disabled'});
            this.setState({isPrevBtnActive: 'disabled'});
            if(totalPage === listid && totalPage > 1){
                this.setState({isPrevBtnActive: ''});
            }
            else if(listid === 1 && totalPage > 1){
                this.setState({isNextBtnActive: ''});
            }
            else if(totalPage > 1){
                this.setState({isNextBtnActive: ''});
                this.setState({isPrevBtnActive: ''});
            }
        }
          btnIncrementClick() {
              this.setState({upperPageBound: this.state.upperPageBound + this.state.pageBound});
              this.setState({lowerPageBound: this.state.lowerPageBound + this.state.pageBound});
              let listid = this.state.upperPageBound + 1;
              this.setState({ currentPage: listid});
              this.setPrevAndNextBtnClass(listid);
        }
          btnDecrementClick() {
            this.setState({upperPageBound: this.state.upperPageBound - this.state.pageBound});
            this.setState({lowerPageBound: this.state.lowerPageBound - this.state.pageBound});
            let listid = this.state.upperPageBound - this.state.pageBound;
            this.setState({ currentPage: listid});
            this.setPrevAndNextBtnClass(listid);
        }
        btnPrevClick() {
            if((this.state.currentPage -1)%this.state.pageBound === 0 ){
                this.setState({upperPageBound: this.state.upperPageBound - this.state.pageBound});
                this.setState({lowerPageBound: this.state.lowerPageBound - this.state.pageBound});
            }
            let listid = this.state.currentPage - 1;
            this.setState({ currentPage : listid});
            this.setPrevAndNextBtnClass(listid);
        }
        btnNextClick() {
            if((this.state.currentPage +1) > this.state.upperPageBound ){
                this.setState({upperPageBound: this.state.upperPageBound + this.state.pageBound});
                this.setState({lowerPageBound: this.state.lowerPageBound + this.state.pageBound});
            }
            let listid = this.state.currentPage + 1;
            this.setState({ currentPage : listid});
            this.setPrevAndNextBtnClass(listid);
        }
          render() {
            const { todos, currentPage, todosPerPage,upperPageBound,lowerPageBound,isPrevBtnActive,isNextBtnActive } = this.state;
            // Logic for displaying current todos
            const indexOfLastTodo = currentPage * todosPerPage;
            const indexOfFirstTodo = indexOfLastTodo - todosPerPage;
            const currentTodos = todos.slice(indexOfFirstTodo, indexOfLastTodo);

            const renderTodos = currentTodos.map((todo, index) => {
              return <li key={index}>{todo}</li>;
            });

            // Logic for displaying page numbers
            const pageNumbers = [];
            for (let i = 1; i <= Math.ceil(todos.length / todosPerPage); i++) {
              pageNumbers.push(i);
            }

            const renderPageNumbers = pageNumbers.map(number => {
                if(number === 1 && currentPage === 1){
                    return(
                        <li key={number} className='active' id={number}><a href='#' id={number} onClick={this.handleClick}>{number}</a></li>
                    )
                }
                else if((number < upperPageBound + 1) && number > lowerPageBound){
                    return(
                        <li key={number} id={number}><a href='#' id={number} onClick={this.handleClick}>{number}</a></li>
                    )
                }
            });
            let pageIncrementBtn = null;
            if(pageNumbers.length > upperPageBound){
                pageIncrementBtn = <li className=''><a href='#' onClick={this.btnIncrementClick}> &hellip; </a></li>
            }
            let pageDecrementBtn = null;
            if(lowerPageBound >= 1){
                pageDecrementBtn = <li className=''><a href='#' onClick={this.btnDecrementClick}> &hellip; </a></li>
            }
            let renderPrevBtn = null;
            if(isPrevBtnActive === 'disabled') {
                renderPrevBtn = <li className={isPrevBtnActive}><span id="btnPrev"> Prev </span></li>
            }
            else{
                renderPrevBtn = <li className={isPrevBtnActive}><a href='#' id="btnPrev" onClick={this.btnPrevClick}> Prev </a></li>
            }
            let renderNextBtn = null;
            if(isNextBtnActive === 'disabled') {
                renderNextBtn = <li className={isNextBtnActive}><span id="btnNext"> Next </span></li>
            }
            else{
                renderNextBtn = <li className={isNextBtnActive}><a href='#' id="btnNext" onClick={this.btnNextClick}> Next </a></li>
            }
            return (
              <div>
                  <ul>
                  {renderTodos}
                </ul>
                <ul id="page-numbers" className="pagination">
                  {renderPrevBtn}
                  {pageDecrementBtn}
                  {renderPageNumbers}
                  {pageIncrementBtn}
                  {renderNextBtn}
                </ul>
              </div>
            );
          }
        }


        ReactDOM.render(
          <TodoApp />,
          document.getElementById('app')
        );
```

Working demo link : https://codepen.io/mhmanandhar/pen/oEWBqx

Image : [simple react pagination](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57vXp.png)

Answer (score 6):

Here is a way to create your Custom Pagination Component from react-bootstrap lib and this component you can use Throughout your project
[image]

> Your Pagination Component (pagination.jsx or js)

```
import React, { Component } from "react"; 
import { Pagination } from "react-bootstrap"; 
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

export default class PaginationHandler extends Component {  

   constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      paging: {
        offset: 0,
        limit: 10
      },
      active: 0
    };  
    }

  pagingHandler = () => {
    let offset = parseInt(event.target.id);
    this.setState({
      active: offset
    });
    this.props.pageHandler(event.target.id - 1);   };

  nextHandler = () => {
    let active = this.state.active;
    this.setState({
      active: active + 1
    });
    this.props.pageHandler(active + 1);   };

  backHandler = () => {
    let active = this.state.active;
    this.setState({
      active: active - 1
    });
    this.props.pageHandler(active - 1);   };

  renderPageNumbers = (pageNumbers, totalPages) => {
    let { active } = this.state;
    return (
      <Pagination>
        <Pagination.Prev disabled={active < 5} onClick={ active >5 && this.backHandler} />

        {
      pageNumbers.map(number => {
              if (
                number >= parseInt(active) - 3 &&
                number <= parseInt(active) + 3 
              ) {
                return (
                  <Pagination.Item
                    id={number}
                    active={number == active}
                    onClick={this.pagingHandler}
                  >
                    {number}
                  </Pagination.Item>
                );
              } else {
                return null;
              }
        })}
        <Pagination.Next onClick={ active <= totalPages -4 && this.nextHandler} />
      </Pagination>
    );   };

  buildComponent = (props, state) => {
    const { totalPages } = props;
    const pageNumbers = [];
    for (let i = 1; i <= totalPages; i++) {
      pageNumbers.push(i);
    }
    return (
      <div className="pull-right">
      {this.renderPageNumbers(pageNumbers ,totalPages)}
      </div>
    );   
};

  render() {
    return this.buildComponent(this.props, this.state);
  } 

} 
   PaginationHandler.propTypes = 
   {
    paging: PropTypes.object,
    pageHandler: PropTypes.func,
    totalPages: PropTypes.object 
   };
```

> Use of Above Child Component in your Parent Component as shown below

```
import Pagination from "../pagination";

pageHandler = (offset) =>{
      this.setState(({ paging }) => ({
        paging: { ...paging, offset: offset }
      }));
   }
   render() {
    return (
      <div>
         <Pagination
          paging = {paging}
          pageHandler = {this.pageHandler}
          totalPages = {totalPages}>
          </Pagination>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: my table items is not changing in my table area?

Comment: What if there are multiple page numbers i.e. 30,40 etc. ? How will you add "..."?

Answer (score 4):

```
   Sample pagination react js working code 
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import {
    Pagination,
    PaginationItem,
    PaginationLink
    } from "reactstrap";


    let prev  = 0;
    let next  = 0;
    let last  = 0;
    let first = 0;
    export default class SamplePagination extends Component {
       constructor() {
         super();
         this.state = {
           todos: ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','T','v','u','w','x','y','z'],
           currentPage: 1,
           todosPerPage: 3,

         };
         this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
         this.handleLastClick = this.handleLastClick.bind(this);
         this.handleFirstClick = this.handleFirstClick.bind(this);
       }

       handleClick(event) {
         event.preventDefault();
         this.setState({
           currentPage: Number(event.target.id)
         });
       }

       handleLastClick(event) {
         event.preventDefault();
         this.setState({
           currentPage:last
         });
       }
       handleFirstClick(event) {
         event.preventDefault();
         this.setState({
           currentPage:1
         });
       }
       render() {
         let { todos, currentPage, todosPerPage } = this.state;

         // Logic for displaying current todos
         let indexOfLastTodo = currentPage * todosPerPage;
         let indexOfFirstTodo = indexOfLastTodo - todosPerPage;
         let currentTodos = todos.slice(indexOfFirstTodo, indexOfLastTodo);
          prev  = currentPage > 0 ? (currentPage -1) :0;
          last = Math.ceil(todos.length/todosPerPage);
          next  = (last === currentPage) ?currentPage: currentPage +1;

         // Logic for displaying page numbers
         let pageNumbers = [];
         for (let i = 1; i <=last; i++) {
           pageNumbers.push(i);
         }

          return (
           <div>
             <ul>
              {
                currentTodos.map((todo,index) =>{
                  return <li key={index}>{todo}</li>;
                })
              }
             </ul><ul id="page-numbers">
             <nav>
              <Pagination>
              <PaginationItem>
              { prev === 0 ? <PaginationLink disabled>First</PaginationLink> :
                  <PaginationLink onClick={this.handleFirstClick} id={prev} href={prev}>First</PaginationLink>
              }
              </PaginationItem>
              <PaginationItem>
              { prev === 0 ? <PaginationLink disabled>Prev</PaginationLink> :
                  <PaginationLink onClick={this.handleClick} id={prev} href={prev}>Prev</PaginationLink>
              }
              </PaginationItem>
                 {
                  pageNumbers.map((number,i) =>
                  <Pagination key= {i}>
                  <PaginationItem active = {pageNumbers[currentPage-1] === (number) ? true : false} >
                   <PaginationLink onClick={this.handleClick} href={number} key={number} id={number}>
                   {number}
                   </PaginationLink>
                   </PaginationItem>
                  </Pagination>
                )}

             <PaginationItem>
             {
               currentPage === last ? <PaginationLink disabled>Next</PaginationLink> :
               <PaginationLink onClick={this.handleClick} id={pageNumbers[currentPage]} href={pageNumbers[currentPage]}>Next</PaginationLink>
             }
             </PaginationItem>

             <PaginationItem>
             {
               currentPage === last ? <PaginationLink disabled>Last</PaginationLink> :
               <PaginationLink onClick={this.handleLastClick} id={pageNumbers[currentPage]} href={pageNumbers[currentPage]}>Last</PaginationLink>
             }
             </PaginationItem>
             </Pagination>
              </nav>
             </ul>
           </div>
         );
       }
     }

     ReactDOM.render(
      <SamplePagination />,
      document.getElementById('root')
    );
```

Answer (score 3):

I recently created this Pagination component that implements paging logic like Google's search results:

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
 
const propTypes = {
    items: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    onChangePage: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    initialPage: PropTypes.number   
}
 
const defaultProps = {
    initialPage: 1
}
 
class Pagination extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { pager: {} };
    }
 
    componentWillMount() {
        this.setPage(this.props.initialPage);
    }
 
    setPage(page) {
        var items = this.props.items;
        var pager = this.state.pager;
 
        if (page < 1 || page > pager.totalPages) {
            return;
        }
 
        // get new pager object for specified page
        pager = this.getPager(items.length, page);
 
        // get new page of items from items array
        var pageOfItems = items.slice(pager.startIndex, pager.endIndex + 1);
 
        // update state
        this.setState({ pager: pager });
 
        // call change page function in parent component
        this.props.onChangePage(pageOfItems);
    }
 
    getPager(totalItems, currentPage, pageSize) {
        // default to first page
        currentPage = currentPage || 1;
 
        // default page size is 10
        pageSize = pageSize || 10;
 
        // calculate total pages
        var totalPages = Math.ceil(totalItems / pageSize);
 
        var startPage, endPage;
        if (totalPages <= 10) {
            // less than 10 total pages so show all
            startPage = 1;
            endPage = totalPages;
        } else {
            // more than 10 total pages so calculate start and end pages
            if (currentPage <= 6) {
                startPage = 1;
                endPage = 10;
            } else if (currentPage + 4 >= totalPages) {
                startPage = totalPages - 9;
                endPage = totalPages;
            } else {
                startPage = currentPage - 5;
                endPage = currentPage + 4;
            }
        }
 
        // calculate start and end item indexes
        var startIndex = (currentPage - 1) * pageSize;
        var endIndex = Math.min(startIndex + pageSize - 1, totalItems - 1);
 
        // create an array of pages to ng-repeat in the pager control
        var pages = _.range(startPage, endPage + 1);
 
        // return object with all pager properties required by the view
        return {
            totalItems: totalItems,
            currentPage: currentPage,
            pageSize: pageSize,
            totalPages: totalPages,
            startPage: startPage,
            endPage: endPage,
            startIndex: startIndex,
            endIndex: endIndex,
            pages: pages
        };
    }
 
    render() {
        var pager = this.state.pager;
 
        return (
            <ul className="pagination">
                <li className={pager.currentPage === 1 ? 'disabled' : ''}>
                    <a onClick={() => this.setPage(1)}>First</a>
                </li>
                <li className={pager.currentPage === 1 ? 'disabled' : ''}>
                    <a onClick={() => this.setPage(pager.currentPage - 1)}>Previous</a>
                </li>
                {pager.pages.map((page, index) =>
                    <li key={index} className={pager.currentPage === page ? 'active' : ''}>
                        <a onClick={() => this.setPage(page)}>{page}</a>
                    </li>
                )}
                <li className={pager.currentPage === pager.totalPages ? 'disabled' : ''}>
                    <a onClick={() => this.setPage(pager.currentPage + 1)}>Next</a>
                </li>
                <li className={pager.currentPage === pager.totalPages ? 'disabled' : ''}>
                    <a onClick={() => this.setPage(pager.totalPages)}>Last</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        );
    }
}
 
Pagination.propTypes = propTypes;
Pagination.defaultProps
export default Pagination;
```

And here's an example App component that uses the Pagination component to paginate a list of 150 example items:

```
import React from 'react';
import Pagination from './Pagination';
 
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
 
        // an example array of items to be paged
        var exampleItems = _.range(1, 151).map(i => { return { id: i, name: 'Item ' + i }; });
 
        this.state = {
            exampleItems: exampleItems,
            pageOfItems: []
        };
 
        // bind function in constructor instead of render (https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-no-bind.md)
        this.onChangePage = this.onChangePage.bind(this);
    }
 
    onChangePage(pageOfItems) {
        // update state with new page of items
        this.setState({ pageOfItems: pageOfItems });
    }
 
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="text-center">
                        <h1>React - Pagination Example with logic like Google</h1>
                        {this.state.pageOfItems.map(item =>
                            <div key={item.id}>{item.name}</div>
                        )}
                        <Pagination items={this.state.exampleItems} onChangePage={this.onChangePage} />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <hr />
                <div className="credits text-center">
                    <p>
                        <a href="http://jasonwatmore.com" target="_top">JasonWatmore.com</a>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
 
export default App;
```

For more details and a live demo you can check out [this post](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2017/03/14/react-pagination-example-with-logic-like-google)

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-js-pagination instead of reinventing the wheel?

Comment: @Jason I have one issue in your implementation which I have raised on the git repo, can you have a look?
https://github.com/cornflourblue/react-pagination-example/issues/8

Answer (score 2):

Please see this code sample in codesandbox

https://codesandbox.io/s/pagino-13pit

[image]

```
import Pagino from "pagino";
import { useState, useMemo } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [pages, setPages] = useState([]);

  const pagino = useMemo(() => {
    const _ = new Pagino({
      showFirst: false,
      showLast: false,
      onChange: (page, count) => setPages(_.getPages())
    });

    _.setCount(10);

    return _;
  }, []);

  const hanglePaginoNavigation = (type) => {
    if (typeof type === "string") {
      pagino[type]?.();
      return;
    }

    pagino.setPage(type);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Page: {pagino.page}</h1>
      <ul>
        {pages.map((page) => (
          <button key={page} onClick={() => hanglePaginoNavigation(page)}>
            {page}
          </button>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1- Use `react-bootstrap`

```
import React from "react";
import { Pagination } from "react-bootstrap";
import Link from "next/link";

interface PaginateProps {
  pages: number;
  page: number;
  keyword?: string;
  isAdmin?: boolean;
}

const Paginate = ({
  pages,
  page,
  // keyword is for searching
  keyword = "",
  isAdmin = false,
}: PaginateProps) => {
  return pages > 1 ? (
    <Pagination>
      {/* keys returns a new Array iterator contians the keys for each index */} 
      // pages is total number of pages
      {[...Array(pages).keys()].map((x) => (
        // this is next.js component. you could use react Link
        <Link
          passHref
          key={x + 1}
          href={
            !isAdmin
              // since array indexing starts at 0, use x+1
              ? `/?keyword=${keyword}&page=${x + 1}`
              : `/admin/productlist/?keyword=${keyword}&page=${x + 1}`
          }
        >
          <Pagination.Item active={x + 1 === page}>{x + 1}</Pagination.Item>
        </Link>
      ))}
    </Pagination>
  ) : null;
};

export default Paginate;
```

then use it in a page.

```
    <Paginate page={page} pages={pages} keyword={keyword} />
```

2- use react-js pagination

```
  import Pagination from "react-js-pagination";

  // bootstrap class to center 
  <div className="d-flex justify-content-center mt-5">
      <Pagination
        activePage={page}
        itemsCountPerPage={resPerPageValue}
        totalItemsCount={Count}
        onChange={handlePagination}
        nextPageText={"Next"}
        prevPageText={"Prev"}
        firstPageText={"First"}
        lastPageText={"Last"}
        // overwriting the style
        itemClass="page-item"
        linkClass="page-link"
      />
    </div>
```

onChange handler

```
 const handlePagination = (pageNumber) => {
    // window.location.href will reload entire page
    router.push(`/?page=${pageNumber}`);
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented pagination + search in ReactJs, see the output:
[Pagination in React](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8n6D7.gif)

View complete code on GitHub: https://github.com/navanathjadhav/generic-pagination

Also visit this article for step by step implementation of pagination: https://everblogs.com/react/3-simple-steps-to-add-pagination-in-react/

Answer (score 0):

I've recently created library which helps to cope with pagination cases like:

- storing normalized data in Redux
- caching pages based on search filters
- simplified react-virtualized list usage
- refreshing results in background
- storing last visited page and used filters

[DEMO](https://tranzystor.github.io/redux-cached-pagination/#/) page implements all above features.

Source code you can find on [Github](https://github.com/Tranzystor/redux-cached-pagination)

Answer (score 0):

A ReactJS dumb component to render pagination. You can also use this Library:

```
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-js-pagination
```

Some Examples are Here:

http://vayser.github.io/react-js-pagination/

OR

You can also Use this https://codepen.io/PiotrBerebecki/pen/pEYPbY

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you make it as a separate component 
I have used [tabler-react](http://tabler-react.com)

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Page,  Button } from "tabler-react";
class PaginateComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            array: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
            limit: 5, // optional
            page: 1
        };
    }

paginateValue = (page) => {
    this.setState({ page: page });
    console.log(page) // access this value from parent component 
}

paginatePrevValue = (page) => {
    this.setState({ page: page });
    console.log(page)  // access this value from parent component
}
paginateNxtValue = (page) => {
       this.setState({ page: page });
       console.log(page)  // access this value from parent component
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>    
                <div>
                    <Button.List>
                        <Button
                      disabled={this.state.page === 0}
                      onClick={() => this.paginatePrevValue(this.state.page - 1)}
                            outline
                            color="primary"
                        >
                            Previous
                      </Button>

                        {this.state.array.map((value, index) => {
                            return (
                                <Button
                                    onClick={() => this.paginateValue(value)}
                                    color={
                                        this.state.page === value
                                            ? "primary"
                                            : "secondary"
                                    }
                                >
                                    {value}
                                </Button>
                            );
                        })}

                        <Button
                            onClick={() => this.paginateNxtValue(this.state.page + 1)}
                            outline
                            color="secondary"
                        >
                            Next
                      </Button>
                    </Button.List>
                </div>
            </div>

        )
    }
}

export default PaginateComponent;
```

Answer (score -5):

Give you a pagination component, which is maybe a little difficult to understand for newbie to `react`:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/pagination

Comment: Yah.. It's bit difficult for a newbie. anyways thanks for your help..:-)