# How to display large dataset in select box in react?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, antd

I have a large set of data need to listout in `antd select box`.

the list is almost **126463** numbers of record

**ex: ['gmail.com', 'yahoo.com', 'xyz.com'......]**

> I am using React antd select box to display these many data. but it
>   becomes unresponsive and the browser hangs.
>
> Can anyone help me how to handel this large data to display in antd
>   select box ?

**Code:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { Select } from 'antd';
import axios from 'axios';

export class EmailData extends React {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            email_domain_list: []
        }
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        this.listOutEmailDomain()
    }

    listOutEmailDomain() {
        const getEmailDomain = {
          method: "GET",
          url: 'API TO GET EMAIL DOMAINS',
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
          },
        };

        let resp = await axios(getEmailDomain);
        if (resp) {
          this.setState({
            email_domain_list:  resp.data.data
          });
        }
    }

    render(){

        return <div>
                        <h6 className="email"><b>Email Data</b></h6>
                        <div>
                            <Select
                                showSearch
                                mode="tags"
                                size="large"
                                id={fieldConstants.emailDomain}
                                value={this.state.email_domain}
                                onChange={(e) => this.emailDomainChange(e)}
                                style={{ width: 390, marginLeft: 10 }} >
                                {
                                    this.state.email_domain_list.map((item, index) => {
                                        return (
                                            <Option value={item} key={index}>{item}</Option>
                                        )
                                    })
                                }
                            </Select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
    }
}
```

Comment: You can fetch the top-level some amount of data. give user search in select and then base user keyword fetch data from database

Comment: Try pagination. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55641734/7906671)