# Require Top pagination using reactable library

Tags: reactjs, pagination, reactable

[reactable](https://github.com/abdulrahman-khankan/reactable)

In a react project, pagination is implemented using reactable (link above) library. but by default, pagination is on the bottom. I am trying to show pagination on top and bottom both but there are no props in the source code doc which I can use to achieve the functionality. I am not allowed to fork the repository and change the code because it will lead to complexity in the future for the client. Anyone please help. I am digging it for the past two weeks. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40232847/how-to-implement-pagination-in-reactjs) and build your own Pagination component.

Comment: reactable is being used in the whole application due to its sorting and other cool features. so implementing the pagination and all functionality  is not good to go. I have tried a couple of ways like inserting inner HTML of bottom pagination on top using "insert-adjacent HTML" and I am getting the pagination element on top but that pagination is not clickable and working.

Comment: The given link also does the same as `reactable`. You can just iterate over your data and have a hyperlink for the same. This also allows you to have a customized ui.

Comment: But our requirement is to use reactable libarary any how. I think it's not possible without forking it.