# How do I paginate data in ReactJs?

Tags: reactjs, pagination

I have data which I populated from the network tab of an ecommerce website, if I have the data of 20 pages in one "data.json" file, how do I make it such so that one page displays first 20 items, the next page shows the next 20 items?

Comment: Keep track of a `page` and `rowsPerPage` variable. Slice the data array like this: `data.slice((page - 1) * rowsPerPage, page * rowsPerPage)`. If the number of rows is constant, you don't need a state variable, and can just hardcode it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to implement pagination in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40232847/how-to-implement-pagination-in-react)

Answer (score 0):

First I would create some IIFE curried function which first loads `data.json` file and returns function which paginates data.

```
const getPagedItems = (() => {
  const allItemsPromise = loadDataJson();

  return (page, pageSize) => {
    return allItemsPromise.then(allItems => {
      const it = page * pageSize;
      const items = allItems.slice(it, it + pageSize);

      return {
        items,
        totalCount: allItems.length
      }
    });
  }
})();
```

As for the component structure, I would create List component for rendering items and Paginator component for traversing items, setting items per page etc.

Or import some 3rd part component which handles these things like [MUI React Table](https://mui.com/components/tables/#sorting-amp-selecting)

```
<Page>
    <List items={items} />
    <Paginator
       page={page}
       totalPages={totalPages}
       itemsPerPage={itemsPerPage}
       onSelectPage={onSelectPage}
       onSelectItemsPerPage={onSelectItemsPerPage} />
</Page>
```

**Example**

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

const itemsPerPageList = [5, 10];

// data.json
const getAllItems = () => Promise.resolve(Array(23).fill(0).map((pr, index) => ({
  id: index,
  name: `Item ${index + 1}`
})));

const getPagedItems = (() => {
  const allItemsPromise = getAllItems();

  return (page, pageSize) => {
    return allItemsPromise.then(allItems => {
      const it = page * pageSize;
      const items = allItems.slice(it, it + pageSize);

      return {
        items,
        totalCount: allItems.length
      }
    });
  }
})();

const List = ({
items,
}) => {
  return <div>
    {items.map(pr => <div key={pr.id}>{pr.name}</div>)}
  </div>
}

const Paginator = ({
  itemsPerPage,
  page,
  totalPages,
  onSelectPage,
  onSelectItemsPerPage
}) => {
  const _onSelectPage = (event) => {
    const page = Number(event.currentTarget.dataset.page);
    onSelectPage(page);
  }
  
  const _onSelectItemsPerPage = (event) => {
    const page = Number(event.currentTarget.value);
    onSelectItemsPerPage(page);
  }

  return <div className="paginator">
    <div>Items per page</div>
    <select onChange={_onSelectItemsPerPage}>
      {itemsPerPageList.map(pr => <option key={pr} value={pr}>{pr}</option>)}
    </select>
    <div>Page {page} of {totalPages}</div>
    <button
      data-page={page - 1}
      disabled={!page}
      onClick={_onSelectPage}
      type="button">Previous</button>
    <button
      data-page={page + 1}
      disabled={page === totalPages}
      onClick={_onSelectPage}
      type="button">Next</button>
  </div>
}

const App = () => {
  const [{
    items,
    page,
    totalPages,
    itemsPerPage
  }, setState] = useState({
    items: [],
    page: 0,
    totalPages,
    itemsPerPage: 5,
  });
  
  useEffect(() => {
    let unmounted = false;
  
    getPagedItems(page, itemsPerPage).then(result => {
      const totalPages = Math.floor(result.totalCount / itemsPerPage);
    
    if(unmounted) {
      return;
    }
    
    setState(state => ({
      ...state,
      items: result.items,
      totalPages,
    }));
    });
    
    return () => unmounted = true;
    
  }, []);
  
  const onSelectPage = (page) => {
    getPagedItems(page, itemsPerPage)
    .then(result => {
      setState(state => ({
        ...state,
        page,
        items: result.items,
      }));
    })
  }
  
  const onSelectItemsPerPage = (itemsPerPage) => {
    const page = 0;
    getPagedItems(page, itemsPerPage)
    .then(result => {
      const totalPages = Math.floor(result.totalCount / itemsPerPage);

      setState(state => ({
        ...state,
        page,
        items: result.items,
        itemsPerPage,
        totalPages,
      }));
    })
  }

  return <div>
   <List items={items}/>
   <Paginator
    page={page}
    totalPages={totalPages}
    itemsPerPage={itemsPerPage}
    onSelectPage={onSelectPage}
    onSelectItemsPerPage={onSelectItemsPerPage}
   />
  </div>
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
```

```css
.paginator {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```