# How to add pagination in accordian using react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Hey Folks I need to add pagination in my accordian. Accordian is coming perfectyly and data is rendering through api call. Now I need to add pagination in it. Can anyone help me with that

Comment: add your sample code, using API or fixed JSON, better create a code sandbox with working code and share the link. I will update solution there. as you know we cant identify the method without seeing the code

Comment: please add the sample code and read how to write question on stack overflow. anyways without review code i can only suggest you a third party npm react-paginate and you can read this also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40232847/how-to-implement-pagination-in-react

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to implement pagination in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40232847/how-to-implement-pagination-in-react)